# Evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x+7} - \sqrt[\leftroot{5}\uproot{0}3]{4x+19}}{x-2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve this limit, but I don't know how. I tried variable sustitutions but it didn't work out. I used $u= x+7$ or $u^3=4x+19$, for example.

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x+7} - \sqrt[\leftroot{5}\uproot{0}3]{4x+19}}{x-2}$$

Any hint given is appreciated.

Comment: @PeterForeman It was a typo. Edited

Comment: Are you allowed to use l'hopital's rule?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you actually meant $\lim_{x\to2}$, your limit is equal to$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt{x+7}-3}{x-2}-\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{4x+19}-3}{x-2}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Then for the second $$\sqrt[3]{4x+19}=y$$

Comment: With this hint I solved this in like 1 minute, what is the "intuition" below this trick of the $-3$?. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you have a limit like $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x-a}$, where $f$ and $g$ are such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)-g(x)=0$, then, assuming that $a$ belongs to the domains of $f$ and of $g$ and that both function are continuous there, your limit is equal to$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}.$$And now, assuming that $f$ and $g$ are actually differentiable at $a$, this is equal to $f'(a)-g'(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{9+h}-\sqrt[3]{27+4h}}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3\sqrt{1+\frac{h}9}-3\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{4h}{27}}}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3\left(1+\frac{h}{18}+o(h)\right)-3\left(1+\frac{4h}{81}+o(h)\right)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{h}{6}-\frac{4h}{27}+o(h)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac1{54}+o(1)\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac1{54}}\\
\end{align}$$
where I have used the fact that as $x\to0$
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+o(x)$$
otherwise known as the generalized binomial expansion.

Comment: @Rodrigo. Using the first expression of Peter's, you can "subtract and add" $3$ and split the expression into two. The first expression would be a direct definition of the derivative. The second one can be molded into a derivative as well after subbing $4h=t$. I did not post it as an answer, because Hospital is not allowed, and using a derivative is "close" to Hospital Rule, though others may be more liberal regarding this. Anyway, this method also yields the answer..

Comment: @imranfat Yet the accepted answer uses this technique even though it is literally L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x-2=h$

Now as $[2,3]=6$

$$F=\dfrac{(9+h)^{1/2}-(27+4h)^{1/3}}h$$ $$=\dfrac{(9+h)^3-(27+4h)^2}h\cdot\dfrac1{\sum_{r=0}^5(9+h)^{r/2}(27+4h)^{(5-r)/3}}$$

$$=\dfrac{3\cdot9^2-216}{6\cdot3^5}=?$$